# How can I check if Google Identity Service migration was successful?

Tags: vuejs2, google-api, google-signin

We have followed the Google Identity migration documentation and replaced the new code but used existing google OAuth client ID.
Previously, before migration we used to get a warning in console, please see the image attached-

[image: Warning in console]

Now, after we have added the new code the warning message is not showing in the console. Below is the new console image

[image: After new code no warning]

But still we have received one reminder mail from Google with our app name and OAuth key that we still need to migrate.
So we are confused if the migration was successful or not? Please help? Do we have to create a new OAuth client ID and replace?
(**Please note we are not seeing any warning in console related to this.**)
Here is our code snippet-

```
<div class="bg-google text-white pt-3 pb-2 px-4 rounded-lg cursor-pointer ml-4 mr-4" @click="SocialLogin">
<img src="@/assets/images/pages/login/google.svg"/><span>Sign in with Google</span>
</div>


mounted() {
            this.tokenClient= google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: process.env.VUE_APP_GOOGLE_OAUTH_KEY,
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            prompt: "consent",
            callback: tokenResponse => this.handleCredentialResponse(tokenResponse) // your function to handle the response after login. 'access_token' will be returned as property on the response
            });

        },


methods: {
       SocialLogin() {
            this.tokenClient.requestAccessToken();
            },

            async handleCredentialResponse(response) {
                this.$helper.showLoading();
                const userInfo = await new Promise(resolve => {
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.open('GET', `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${response.access_token}`)
                xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) 
                resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
                else resolve({ err: '404' });
                };
                xhr.send();
            });
            if(userInfo){
              localStorage.setItem("user_email", userInfo.email);

              }
            
            },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the team apparently there is a back log for these messages so they may have detected a few weeks ago that you were still using the old library and the message is just getting sent now.

You know you have upgraded and are no longer getting the error message so your all good.